# Same input size but cannot fit the model in keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am trying to fit this model in keras but getting this error :

```
 Namespace(batch_size=32, epoch=10, num_classes=2)
Start
Train loading
<class 'numpy.uint8'>
Test loading
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Validation loading
done_loading
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 67, in <module>
    validation_data=(x_val, Y_valHot)
  File "/tools/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1581, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/tools/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1414, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/tools/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 153, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected data to have shape (None, 224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (9730, 244, 224, 3)
```

The function used to fit the model is

```
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
          shuffle=True,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid),
          )
```

Can someone tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: Please provide a model summary as well as some info about input and output data.

Comment: It's the densenet model, I'm trying to fine tune.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected data to have shape (None, 224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (9730, 244, 224, 3)` it clearly says that while preprocessing that either `X_train` or `X_valid` have `(9730, **244**, 224, 3)` instead of `(9730, **224**, 224, 3)`

Comment: I'm really careless. Really sorry, the numbers were too similar, I didn't notice. Thank you so much for your reply

Comment: Yeah, if nothing else, closing the question would be highly appreciated.